# Update a UI state when all Async methods in different presenters are complete

Tags: c#, async-await, mvp

I have a question regarding the elegance and best practice on the code bellow.
The concept of the app:

1. I have a main form that invokes user controls
2. This main form has a progress control that show the user the progress of several task through event handlers that are attached to user controls as needed
3. The View (user control) "ViewPhase1" has the event of progress changing
4. This View has two presenters
5. Each of these presenters have async tasks
6. When a task is about to start progress is changed
7. When a task has ended I check if both tasks have been completed and if so progress is set to 100% (done)

Because I have two separated presenters that call Async methods, one of them can complete before the other, so I have created two properties "DoneTasksWork" in the View to be able in the presenter that allows to know if Tasks of each Presenter are complete.
If both are completed then the progress in the UI is set as 100% (and enables all controls within), if not progress will remain as still running.

Is this a elegant solution? Thinking of this case, progress control only at complete state when Async methods in different classes are complete, can I approach with another solution instead of boolean properties beeing used as flags?

Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Project.Utilities;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class ViewPhase1 : UserControl, IViewPhase1Work1, IViewPhase1Work2
    {
        private PresenterPhase1Work1 _presenterPhase1Work1;
        private PresenterPhase1Work2 _presenterPhase1Work2;

        public ViewPhase1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenterPhase1Work1 = new PresenterPhase1Work1(this);
            _presenterPhase1Work2 = new PresenterPhase1Work2(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is listened by form that invokes this user control and updates progress control.
        /// </summary>
        public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChangedEvent;
        public void OnProgressHandler(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                if (this.ProgressChangedEvent != null)
                {
                    ProgressChangedEvent(this, e);
                }
            });
        }
        public void ShowException(string exMessage, MessageBoxButtons bts, MessageBoxIcon icon)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("", exMessage, bts, icon);
        }
        public DataGridView GridInvoices { get; set; }
        public DataGridView GridReceipts { get; set; }
        public DataGridView GridProducts { get; set; }
        public DataGridView GridCustomers { get; set; }
        bool IViewPhase1Work1.DoneTasksWork { get; set; }
        bool IViewPhase1Work2.DoneTasksWork { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IViewProgress
    {
        event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChangedEvent;
        void OnProgressHandler(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e);
    }

    public interface IViewPhase1Work1 : IViewProgress, IViewException
    {
        bool DoneTasksWork { get; set; }
        DataGridView GridProducts { get; set; }
        DataGridView GridCustomers { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IViewPhase1Work2 : IViewProgress, IViewException
    {
        bool DoneTasksWork { get; set; }
        DataGridView GridInvoices { get; set; }
        DataGridView GridReceipts { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IViewException
    {
        void ShowException(string exMessage, MessageBoxButtons bts, MessageBoxIcon icon);
    }

    public class PresenterPhase1Work1
    {
        private readonly IViewPhase1Work1 _view;

        public PresenterPhase1Work1(IViewPhase1Work1 view)
        {
            _view = view;
            GetInformation();
        }

        private void GetInformation()
        {
            try
            {
                var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetDataProducts());
                var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetDataCustomers());
                Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

                _view.GridProducts.DataSource = task1.Result;
                _view.GridCustomers.DataSource = task2.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _view.ShowException(ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            finally
            {
                _view.DoneTasksWork = true;
                _view.OnProgressHandler(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(_view.DoneTasksWork && _view.DoneTasksWork ? 100 : 50, _view.DoneTasksWork && _view.DoneTasksWork ? "Done" : "Getting data"));
            }
        }

        private async Task<object> GetDataCustomers()
        {
            return await Util.GetDataCustomerAsync();
        }
        private async Task<object> GetDataProducts()
        {
            return await Util.GetDataProductsAsync();
        }
    }

    public class PresenterPhase1Work2
    {
        private readonly IViewPhase1Work2 _view;

        public PresenterPhase1Work2(IViewPhase1Work2 view)
        {
            _view = view;
            GetInformation();
        }

        private void GetInformation()
        {
            try
            {
                var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetDataInvoices());
                var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetDataReceipts());
                Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

                _view.GridInvoices.DataSource = task1.Result;
                _view.GridReceipts.DataSource = task2.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _view.ShowException(ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            finally
            {
                _view.DoneTasksWork = true;
                _view.OnProgressHandler(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(_view.DoneTasksWork && _view.DoneTasksWork ? 100 : 50, _view.DoneTasksWork && _view.DoneTasksWork ? "Done" : "Getting data"));
            }
        }

        private async Task<object> GetDataInvoices()
        {
            return await Util.GetDataInvoicesAsync();
        }

        private async Task<object> GetDataReceipts()
        {
            return await Util.GetDataReceiptsAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant solution it is not. Let me explain.

Exactly what do you expect to happen calling `Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` without using `await`? 
I will tell you: it runs straight through and will block on `_view.GridInvoices.DataSource = task1.Result;` and then possible on next line as well.

So, in order to solve this the method (in `PresenterPhase1Work1` but it also applies to the other presenter as well):

```
private void GetInformation()
    {
        try
        {
            var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetDataProducts());
            var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetDataCustomers());
            Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

            _view.GridProducts.DataSource = task1.Result;
            _view.GridCustomers.DataSource = task2.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _view.ShowException(ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        finally
        {
            _view.DoneTasksWork = true;
            _view.OnProgressHandler(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(_view.DoneTasksWork && _view.DoneTasksWork ? 100 : 50, _view.DoneTasksWork && _view.DoneTasksWork ? "Done" : "Getting data"));
        }
    }
```

could be changed to:

```
private async Task GetInformationAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetDataProducts());
            var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetDataCustomers());

            await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);
            _view.OnProgressHandler(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(50, "Getting data"));

            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
            _view.OnProgressHandler(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(100, "Done"));

            _view.GridProducts.DataSource = await task1;
            _view.GridCustomers.DataSource = await task2;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _view.ShowException(ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Now, calling async methods in the constructor is a bad idea. Constructors don't allow using the `async` keyword. So you have to redesign your classes. So I would make the `GetInformation` method public and call and await the method somewhere else in the view. Immediately after the call `await presenterPhase1Work1.GetMethodAsync();` in your view you know that piece of work is done. So no more need for this Boolean flag.

It does mean your `ViewPhase1` needs to have another method to call the
`await presenterPhase1Work1.GetMethodAsync();` method because also there you cannot do this in the constructor.

Waiting for completion of data loading in a constructor is never a good idea IMHO, whether it is done in a background thread or not.

Comment: Thank you! You're right about the missing async keywords. also thanks about the WhenAny , did not think about that solution. Now you have mentioned the async method being called in the constructor, but in this case the thing is that de data gathering occurs when the form is loaded, meaning that the form (view) constructor initalizes the presenters private fields, by calling the presenters constructors - and there is where the data gathering methods are called. So in this case without a user interaction besides opening a form I'm finding dificult to use another approach.. thanks again!

Comment: Can't you load the data in the override of `Form.OnLoad` or `Form.OnShown` ? That way you can await the presenter there and the user still does not have to do anything.

Comment: Yes and that was my first idea also, but the presenter constructor will still call the async load data methods. I believe this also falls down in the bad practice you mentioned.

Comment: what if the Form (view) creates the presenter in the constructor and calls the presenter LoadData method (with the code of the current presenter constructor) in the `Form.Onload` or `Form.OnShown`?

Comment: yes, but in MVP pattern, the Presenter should not have any methods that the view can call, as View should not know which Presenter is controlling it. That's the thing that got me using Presenter constructor to get all data that the View needs.

Comment: How does you view interact with the presenter, or vice versa? Surely there must be a way other then via the constructor?

Comment: By events. Ok got it ;) listen on the Presenter the view LoadEvent and do data load from presenter listen method.